# init.d script for daemon - cannot remove pidfile

Tags: bash, ubuntu, init.d

Have problems removing a pidfile when stopping a daemon on ubuntu (14.04).

I start the daemon with:

```
log_daemon_msg "Starting $DAEMON_NAME"
start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pid --user $DAEMON_USER --chuid $DAEMON_USER --startas $DAEMON
log_end_msg $?
```

Note the use of --make-pid which I need or no pidfile is created. To stop I have:

```
log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DAEMON_NAME"
start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE --retry 10
log_end_msg $?
rm $PIDFILE
```

I would like to use the flag --remove-pidfile rather than the rm (as I am trying to make this as generic (cross-distro)) as possible but it results in an error.

Checking the man page (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html) there appears to be no --remove-flag for ubuntu although it is mentioned for other distros.

Does anyone know any flags that would do this or should I just stick with rm?

Comment: What are you starting and stopping? If the program you are running runs `setuid` another user, you may not have privileges to delete the pidfile created. Have you tried the same as root?

Comment: a custom python script, I am using sudo service to start/stop it and it drops to user level.

Comment: That should be fine, I've just run into some strange issues where the executable runs as a custom user. That can cause head scratching at times.

Comment: If the version of `start-stop-daemon` on ubutu doesn't have that flag then I think what you are discovering is that (in the interest of making this generic) you should avoid it and stick to doing it yourself.

Comment: Etan - sounds good, I will stick to the current way then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the version of `start-stop-daemon` on ubutu doesn't have that flag then I think what you are discovering is that (in the interest of making this generic) you should avoid it and stick to doing it yourself. – Etan Reisner